# Run PHP, wait; run JavaScript, wait; then submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

What I need to do:

I have an upload form with a file input and hidden text inputs. The user uploads an image, the image gets manipulated and then sent to remote server for processing which takes a few seconds, then the remote server sends the finalized images back to the home server where they are saved in a new folder. JavaScript needs to reach these new images to do further data processing on the newly saved images (which also takes a second). Only after JavaScript has done its thing and updated the form's input variables can the form be submitted.

Right now I've got all of the separate pieces working, but executing everything in one click has proven to be a challenge.

My code for uploading the images:

**PHP:**

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 //do image manipulation and save new files using PHP
 }
```

**JS:**

```
 function furtherProcessing() {
 //do further processing on newly saved images in newly created directory,
 //update hidden input variables for the form
 }
```

**PHP again:**

```
 if(isset($_POST['input_variables'])){
 //send these variables to SQL database
 }
```

I know trying to use JavaScript to get the newly saved images isn't an ideal approach, but the framework that I'm using is only available in JavaScript. Is this even possible with one click?

Comment: Can you give us a real example of exactly what each piece is doing step by step? Javascript can only process images on the client side.

Comment: What you're looking for is called AJAX. AJAX is also JavaScript and can process anything, not just images, @mkaatman

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

In your HTML, add `data-processed="false"` to your form like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" name="q_data" data-processed="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In your jQuery call this to submit the images via ajax:

```
$("form[name='q_data']").submit(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var processed = $this.data('processed')
  if (processed == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: "upload.php", 
      type: "POST",
      data: formData ,
      async: false,
      success: function(msg) {
        //alert(msg);
        if (msg !== 'success') {
          $this.data('processed', true)
          furtherProcessing();
        }
      },
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  }
});

function furtherProcessing() {
  //do further processing on newly saved images in newly created directory,
  //update hidden input variables for the form
  $("form[name='q_data']").submit();
}
```

In `some-page.php` do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['some-image-input-name'])){
 //do image manipulation and save new files using PHP

 return 'success'
}
```

However, if it were me, I'd have that first ajax call (that saves the images) simply return the urls for the saved images, then there is no need for a second ajax call to retrieve them which I assume is what you are doing now

Comment: I've got the hidden input fields to update but now it won't submit the form. I'm using

Comment: @bradical14 did you update `$("form[name='some-second-form']").submit();` to use a selector that is appropriate for your form?

Comment: *I've got the hidden input fields to update but now it won't submit the form. I'm using:
     `if(msg=='success'){ 
     furtherProcessing();
     $("form[name='submit']").submit;
     }`

I'm only using one form in this case

Comment: `$("form[name='submit']").submit()` looks to be wrong, I doubt you have a form with the name `submit` it's more likely that the *form's submit **button** has the name `submit`*. Try changing it to `$("form[name='form-name']").submit()` where `form-name` is the name on your form or `$("button[name='submit']").click()` if that is the only button that has that name. You could also give the form or button an ID and use that if you prefer

Comment: I've tried all of your suggestions and double-checked my selectors, but I haven't gotten any of these to work, sadly. Is it possible that after the `preventDefault();` statemtent that the browser is preventing further submissions on the form? I tried putting your initial block of code into a bigger function with the 2nd `$("form[name='form-name']").submit()` out of scope of he `preventDefault();`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @bradical14 can you put all of your code into a jsfiddle so I can see the form? (just the html and the jquery)

Comment: Ok, you have a few issues. First, you have `onclick="newfunc();"` on your submit button and then you have a click handler *inside that function* that attaches the very button that was just clicked. Ditch the `onclick="newfunc();"` and the whole `newfunc()` function, all you need is the handler. Second, I see now that you are using just one form, I had assumed there were 2. We can work with that but we'll need a way to tell if the images have been processed, take a look at my update and a demo [working jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tsrvstzf/2/)

Comment: Any chance you meant to put another link or didn't do an update on the JSFidde? It looks like it's the same code that I used

Comment: I've got this to run and it's submitting  the form, but for some reason it's not executing the `furtherProcessing();` function now.

Comment: @bradical14 I dont understand, `furtherProcessing()` is what submits the form the second time. If it gets submitted, the function must be getting called. Are you saying that `furtherProcessing()` gets called and submits the form but does so *before the code above `$("form[name='q_data']").submit();` does it's job?* If so, you must have asynchronous functions like `.ajax()` in the code you havent shown, show me that in a jsFiddle and I can show you how to fix it

Comment: I found the issue-- it was because `var processing`'s variable type was not defined and the rest of the function wouldn't execute after the if statement. So now I have that working. The hidden input fields are updating which shows `furtherProcessing();` is being executed. I also have `$("button[name='submit']").click();` at the end of the `furtherProcessing();` function, but the page does not refresh once `furtherProcessing();` has been completed. Is this to be expected? The form action is `upload.php` (the same page AJAX, JS, the rest of the PHP is)

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by **var processing's variable type was not defined** can you make a new fiddle with your new code

Comment: @bradical14 What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.12.0.min.js